# Dell OptiPlex 7020 display problem

Tags: display, dell, display-resolution

I have a Dell OptiPlex 7020 display problem. Despite upgrading bios A07 to A18 version, whenever I click to open "Settings" in Ubuntu 20.04LTS, display goes black and recovers with lower resolution. I installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS also. But nothing changed.

Could you please offer a solution? Thanks.

Here is the video of problem. You can set the speed to x2:

(sd) https://youtu.be/FoBOgYxz6lE

(hd) https://youtu.be/L1Kaa26umU0

Comment: I'd guess that your video cable might be a problem. Maybe even the monitor. Are you using a VGA/DVI/HDMI cable? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema VGA cable using. After your reply, changed it. But still continues. Some of pc which are the same(we have 26 of optiplex 7020), have a A05 bios version working perfect. So I downgraded bios to A05. But problem still continue although formatted again.

Comment: Swap the monitor. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema You are right! When changed to a HP monitor, everything worked. Now I need to replace all Philips Brilliance 221 monitors. Thank you.

Comment: I'll put together a quickie answer for you. Please accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks! Don't replace ALL of the monitors... only the bad ones.

Comment: I checked it. Very sad to us that monitors weren't used too much. They were almost broken without using. What a pity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

We swapped the video monitor and it all works now.